# unix passwd program location

Tags: unix

I want to copy the passwd program to my own directory but am not able to find it. Can anyone please tell where exactly is the passwd program file located in unix?

Thanks.

Comment: `where passwd` will tell you. And you're wrong, you don't want to copy it to your own directory, because it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding out is easy enough on any *nix machine, by using [`which`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which):

```
[user@server ~]$ which passwd
/usr/bin/passwd
```